# updating sub object in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, casbah

Consider following entry in my mongo collection.

```
{
  "id" : "_0001",
  "map" : {
            "foo" : 1
          }
}
```

Now i need to add an entry to inside map. like

```
{
  "id" : "_0001",
  "map" : {
            "foo" : 1,
            "bar" : 2,
          }
}
```

`map` is not a `list` so i cannot use `$push` there. Is there any way of doing this in mongo. And also I'm accessing the database via casbah. Please note down the casbah codes if you can.

NOTE:- **map should not be a list**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Updating nested documents in mongodb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145956/updating-nested-documents-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
db.test.update({ _id : "_0001"}, { $set : { "map.bar" : 2}})
```